# Access Post ID inside Plugin Template

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to pass a custom parameter from an ACF Field to a function in a wordpress plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/insta-gallery/).

When I declare the variable globally in my functions.php it works fine but the problem I am having is that I need a post ID for me to get the  ACF Field Variable.

When I retrieve the the post ID inside the WP loop and before the content is printed and call the function that retrieves that variable inside the plugin file (in order to get the ID), I get an error.

I somehow need to get the post ID from inside the php file of the plugin.

The order the code is executed is as follows:
1. Custom Code written Template.php File with ACF
2. At the end Template.php file fetches Wordpress Content
3. Inside the Wordpress Content there's a shortcode of the plugin
4. Plugin's shortcode is executed (in best case with my parameter from ACF field)

Comment: _I get an error_ isn't very helpful

Comment: yes I know, but I cant really debug since the plugin tells me that it is unable to load the content. I'm guessing that the variable is just empty in this case

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
function inside_content() {
    global $post;
    your_plugin_function($post->ID);
}

add_action( 'the_content', 'inside_content' );
```

Comment: I've tried something similar, but I can't call the plugin function from the functions.php and if I put the code in the plugin file it doenst work either

Comment: _but I can't call the plugin function from the functions.php_. Why you can't?

Comment: Filepath: insta-gallery/includes/frontend.php line 44 "https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/insta-gallery/tags/2.4.3/includes/frontend.php" is the function return inside another function. I need to change the tag paramenter of this function with my variable from acf - if I put this in my functions.php it doesnt load any images at all